# How to make a line inside the listview depends on the percentage value

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity

[image]I have created the view and set the width size is percentage, but if percentage 100 the view doesn't full occupied, can you tell me the solution also if you have the any different view is available please update the issue.    [image]

![My exact screen like this]
![My screen the if percentage 100% means the blue line shows like this, the screen 54.34% so the blue line half of the line only![My screen the if percentage 100% means the blue line shows like this, the screen 54.34% so the blue line half of the line only]
My screen the if percentage 100% means the blue line shows like this, the screen 54.34% so the blue line half of the line only[image: My screen the if percentage 100% means the blue line shows like this, the screen 54.34% so the blue line half of the line only[3]]

// View layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#fafafa"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".DashboardV4MainActivity" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:visibility="gone" >

        <View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:background="#BDBDBD" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:baselineAligned="false"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:paddingLeft="3dp" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:layout_weight="2"
            android:background="#FFFFFF"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:paddingRight="1dp" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/db_lob"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:paddingLeft="5dp"
                android:text="Own"
                android:textColor="@color/black" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/db_lob_percentage"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="20dp"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:paddingLeft="5dp"
                android:text="100%"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:textSize="10sp" />

            <View
                android:id="@+id/db_lob_percent"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="4dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:background="@color/blue2" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.5"
            android:background="#FFFFFF"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/db_lob_count"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="85"
                android:textColor="@color/black" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.5"
            android:background="#FFFFFF"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/navigation_next_item" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:background="#BDBDBD" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: post the xml of your view

Comment: This is called ProgressBar

Comment: find the width of your device, after it set Layout parameters ( width ).

Comment: The above screen the if percentage 100% means the blue line shows like this, the screen 54.34% so the blue line half of the line only![My screen the if percentage 100% means the blue line shows like this, the screen 54.34% so the blue line half of the line only

Comment: @AlexanderZhak is pointing you where you need to go. A horizontal style ProgressBar, it does this for you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this code to find your screen height and width .

```
    final LinearLayout layout_linearLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.layout_linearLayout);
    layout_linearLayout.post(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            int height = layout_linearLayout.getHeight();
            int width = layout_linearLayout.getWidth();

            Log.e("Height", height + "");

            MySharedPref.getInstance(Login.this).setString(
                    "sendScreenHeight_SPLASHSCREEN", height + "");
            MySharedPref.getInstance(Login.this).setString(
                    "sendScreenWidth_SPLASHSCREEN", width + "");

            setWidth_Percent()
        }
    });
```

after it, set width and height for your layout like this:

```
public void setWidth_Percent(){
    View db_lob_percent = (View) findViewById(R.id.db_lob_percent);

    layoutDialog.setLayoutParams(new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(dialogWidth*3/4+dialogWidth*1/8,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
}
```

**Edit** :

```
    You have width for Green and purple box reduce this width from parent width by using 
this function . pass your width(dp) in this function it will return you the width(pixels)


public static float convertDpToPixel(float dp, Context context) {
    Resources resources = context.getResources();
    DisplayMetrics metrics = resources.getDisplayMetrics();
    float px = dp * (metrics.densityDpi / 160f);
    return px;
}
```

-**Edited 2 :**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#fafafa"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".DashboardV4MainActivity" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:visibility="gone" >

            <View
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="1dp"
                android:background="#BDBDBD" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:baselineAligned="false"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:paddingLeft="3dp" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="60dp"
                android:layout_weight="2"
                android:background="#FFFFFF"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:paddingRight="1dp" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/db_lob"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="30dp"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:paddingLeft="5dp"
                    android:text="Own"
                    android:textColor="#000000" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="60dp"
                android:layout_weight="0.5"
                android:background="#FFFFFF"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:orientation="vertical" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/db_lob_count"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="30dp"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="85"
                    android:textColor="#000000" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="60dp"
                android:layout_weight="0.5"
                android:background="#FFFFFF"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:orientation="vertical" >

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <View
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="1dp"
                android:background="#BDBDBD" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/db_lob_percentage"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="20dp"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:paddingLeft="5dp"
            android:text="100%"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="10sp" />

        <View
            android:id="@+id/db_lob_percent"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="4dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:background="#000fff" />
    </FrameLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks for your code.. But i'm using listview base adpater class i have create the getView() and pass the percentage to view width, it will work. but i need the width size for above image inside green color box,

Comment: sorry.. the above image i need light green box width only no need to dark green width and height.

Comment: you want to set your orange line in whole_width ? if yes hen create this orange line inside frameLayout.

Comment: No, I want set the width bassed on the above percentage, if percentage is 50 means the light green view (orange bar) half of the view inside the light screen box, if percentage 100 means the orange view occupied full inside light green box.

Comment: I think, if i'm using framelayout means, i can't able to achieve the correct solution for this. because the orange line bar only to show the light green color box alone. it doesn't goes full screen.

Comment: can you please post your screenshot with the problem.